# stylesheet async with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, stylesheet

I want to load my javascripts and stylesheets async to have a better loading performance; with javascript I know I can load the javascripts async with:

`javascript_include_tag "application", :async => true`

and it works for the javascripts. But is this isn't possible with the `stylesheet_link_tag` like:

`stylesheet_link_tag "application, :media => "all", :async => true`

also is this the "nice" way to do this? thanks

I'm using rails 3.2.12 and ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 reached End of Life some time ago - you should really look at upgrading.

Comment: @sevenseacat any way to do it in ruby 1.9.2 or 2.0?

Comment: the problem is unrelated to the version of Ruby, I'm simply suggesting that you should really upgrade your app to a newer version.

Answer (score 8):

The `async` attribute is not available on the `<link>` tag. It is only used for asynchronously downloading external script resources.

The idea is that you don't want to delay the CSS download because it is needed to render the page whereas javascript can often be downloaded at the same time as the html and executed when it has completed.

It doesn't make sense for there to be an async option for external css resources.

Comment: I know this is a old comment but for the people that are still reading this: Async is important if you want to delay your non critical styles: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/blocking-resources